# djcelery process keep exiting

Tags: python, django, celery, djcelery

I had a django project where i am using celery. But, when i start the celery worker by django using the command

```
python manage.py celery worker
```

it kept printing the error message about the thread exiting

```
[2014-09-23 20:33:21,555: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-4' pid:6824 exited with exitcode 1
[2014-09-23 20:33:21,555: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-3' pid:6356 exited with exitcode 1
[2014-09-23 20:33:21,555: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-2' pid:7528 exited with exitcode 1
[2014-09-23 20:33:21,555: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-1' pid:5272 exited with exitcode 1
```

what should i do?

Comment: You should start a celery worker with `celery -A your_app_name worker -l info`

Comment: I had tried ,it still not work.

Comment: What error it produced when you run above command?

Answer (score 0):

I strat the worker with the wrong command,

it should be `python manage.py celery -A proj worker --settings=settings`